# Django - POST - save multiple items in queryset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm not sure if the title is correctly describing the issue. If you have a more descriptive title, please edit the title.

I have a following dynamically added input fields:

[image]

The first two rows is the first object, second row is the second object, and so on.... I am trying to save these dynamically added elements to DB by customizing `post()` method.
Using my current version of overriding `post()` method:

```
if 'bha' in request.POST:
    bha_form = BHA_Form(request.POST, instance= #some_kwargs...)
    print(request.POST)
```

it prints the following `queryset`:

`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [# foo_token], 'item_description': ['aaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbb'], 'num_of_jts': ['aaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbb'], 'length': ['aaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbb'], 'cum_length': ['aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb'], 'outer_d': ['aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'], 'inner_d': ['', ''], 'drift_d': ['', ''], 'od_cplg': ['', ''], 'top_thread': ['', ''], 'air_wght': ['', ''], 'make': ['', ''], 'sn': ['', ''], 'bha_component': ['Submit']}>`

As you can see, each input fields have 2 values in a form of list, because there are two objects present on the Front-End. If I just use `bha_form.save()`, it will save only the last value in a queryset list. This is not what I want. I want to use something like `get_or_create()` method to create new objects for each dynamically added elements, or edit objects if they are already present in DB

How should I do this? I guess I can write some long set of codes to get this done, but just curious if there's any elegant way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/) that do exactly what you're asking for : posting many objects at the same time. It is a very clean way to do so.

The documentation in the link above explains how to use it in details.